# The best way to structure this database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

At the moment I'm doing this:

```
gems(id, name, colour, level, effects, source)
```

`id` is the primary key and is not auto-increment.

A typical row of data would look like this:

```
id      =>   40153
name    =>   Veiled Ametrine
colour  =>   Orange
level   =>   80
effects =>   +12 sp, +10 hit
source  =>   Ametrine
```

(Some of you gamers might see what I'm doing here :) )

But I realise this could be sorted a lot better. I have studied database relationships and secondary keys in my A-Level computing class but never got as far as to set one up properly. I just need help with how this database should be organised, like what tables should have what data with what secondary and foreign keys?

I was thinking maybe 3 tables: `gem`, `effects`, `source`. Which then have relationships to each other?

Can anyone shed some light on this? Is a complex way like I'm proposing really the way to go or should I just carry on with what I'm doing?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to be passingly familiar with the environment you're describing (:))
Despite what you have convinced yourself, what you are doing is not particularly complex.

Anyway, currently, you have a table with no relationships. It's simple. It's easy. Each gem exists in the database.

If you were to move to the three tables that you proposed, you would *also* need to include link tables to assemble the tables into useable data, especially since (and mind, I'm not quite sure how your distinctions boil out) the effects and source table are involved in a many-to-x relationship: each gem has up to two effects, and each effect has up to Y gems where it is present // each source has up to Z gems.

I'd stick with the single table. The individual records may be longer, but its *much* simpler, and you'll encounter fewer errors than if you were trying to establish linking tables or the like.

Comment: I may have gone overboard on the extra tables because OP said each gem "can have many effects."  In my opinion, "many" is sufficiently different from "two" to warrant the extra table.

Comment: Yes. 2's the max (assuming he's talking World of Warcraft, and my knowledge thereof isn't too outdated)

Answer (score 0):

Questions to ask yourself:

1. Is there a 1 to 1 relationship between gem, effects, and source?
2. Would you more often be pulling effects without pulling data from gem?

If the proposed tables have a 1 to 1 relationship then I'd suggest leaving them combined in one table.  The only time I would consider splitting them out in this condition is if I only needed data from effects without needing other data AND these tables were going to be large enough to justify having them stored on different drives.  Otherwise, you're just making work for yourself, adding more storage requriements and reaping exactly zero benefits.

Comment: At the moment it'd something like: One gem can have many effects. One gem can have one source. Does that really warrent something like this?

Comment: @James P You're not quite looking at it. One gem has one source, but one source has many gems. That's a many-to-one relationship. Likewise, One gem has 1 or 2 effects, but those effects can have (i.e. appear on) many gems. That's a many-to-many relationship in the worst case, which adds even more relational complexity than a many-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider whether you will need the `effects` information for actual usage, or display only.  If it is display only, no big deal to have it in one column in a table.  If you have to use it, for example to apply the +12 and +10 appropriately, then I think you should put each occurrence of it in a separate column.  Accordingly, you should have a separate table for `effects`, and then a separate table storing which gems have which effects, maybe `gemeffects`.  The `Effects` table might have better descriptions of what "sp" stands for, maybe the min and max ranges, etc.  The `GemEffects` table would just have the gem id, the value, and the effect itself.  For example

**Effects**

```
effect  => hit
desc    => How many hit points
minimum => 0
maximum => 100
```

**GemEffects**

```
id     => 40153
effect => sp
value  => 12
```

and

```
id     => 40153
effect => hit
value  => 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You would answer your own question if you do a simple exercise: describe in a natural, descriptive language your system. Which entities, their attributes, how they interact with other entities, etc. Underline substantives and verbs. Ask what entities do you mean to manage (eg: will there be an interface to manage the "effects" table?) You'll be surprised how it all gets assembled naturally.

Now for your example, I'd suggest two approaches (without syntactic details)

1) to gain experience in relational design, with some complexity overhead, and granular over each entity

- gem (id, name,color_id,source_id,effect_assoc_id)
- color (id, name)
- source (id, name)
- effect (id,value,nature_id)
- nature (id, name)
- effect_assoc (id, gem_id, effect_id)

2) straight to the point, possibly valid depending on the cardinality of your relations

just carry on ;)

From your description, I'd go with #1.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following:

1. Move all effects into their own table (e.g., ID, Name, Description, Enabled, ...)
2. Move source into its own table (e.g., ID, Name, Description, Enabled, ...)
3. Drop gems "effects" column (migrates to step 5 below)
4. Convert the gems "source" column into a foreign key value that corresponds to the PK from the "source" table
5. Add a new table to link a single gem entity to zero or more effect entities

        
   Example: tbl_GemsEffectsLink, with two columns named "GemID" and "EffectID," that by

        
   themselves are foreign keys back to the entity tables and when taken together, make up the 

        
   composite primary key.

        

        
   A sample view of this link table would be as follows:

             
        

         `GemID EffectID
           1      1
           1      2
           2      1
           2      2
           2      3`

So, in summary, you would have the following tables:

1. gems
2. effects
3. source
4. gemseffectslink

With each table having the following columns:

1. gems
        
   id (PK)
        
   name
        
   colour
        
   level
        
   sourceid (FK)
2. effects
        
   id (PK)
        
   name
        
   description
        
   enabled
        
   ...
3. source
        
   id (PK)
        
   name
        
   description
        
   enabled
        
   ...
4. gemseffectslink
        
   gemid (FK)
        
   effectid (FK)

Lastly, this assume each gem can have zero or more effects, a single source (you can enforce NULL or NOT NULL for this gem.sourceid FK field), and that the level integer value is just that (i.e., not representing something more robust and exhaustive in that there exists some type of "Level" entity and the value of "80" in your sample data row uniquely identifies one of these "Level" entities).

Hope this helps!
Michael